# Sharepoint App Multiple Languages Support

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint-2013

I have developed an app for SharePoint and it is available on SharePoint app store. Currently it is in English only. Now i want to add support in multiple languages such as German, Japanese, French. Do i need to make changes only in my code part or while publishing this app, if we choose different languages, will Microsoft take care of it?

Comment: This question might be better suited on the dedicated [SharePoint Stack Exchange website](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/).